# ADB doesn't detect any device

Tags: adb

After some time, I found that my previously working ADB no longer recognized any device.  My phone did not pop up the window asking to verify the computer when I connected it.  Restarting the server, using sudo and adding a new ADB version did not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

When I went to edit my /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file, I found that there was a backup copy from a previous edit.  I deleted the backup copy, restarted the adb server with sudo adb kill-server sudo adb start-server and adb worked on all devices again.

However, I have to reboot the server every few seconds or it fails to recognize the devices again.